# Setting value and dataset-attribute gives me different numbers despite the same variable being set to both?

Tags: javascript, html

it is I, Boogabooga,

I have a conundrum which baffles me greatly.
I have a function which dynamically creates some HTML elements with JS, and when setting the `.value` the results is completely different as to when I set `dataset.value` despite the same variable being assigned to both, **below is my JS**:

```
function displayBox(title, src, id){
    let container = document.createElement('div');
    let list = document.createElement('ul');
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    let image = new Image();
    listItem.innerHTML = title;
    image.src = src;
    listItem.dataset.value = id;
    listItem.value = id;
    listItem.innerHTML += id;
    list.appendChild(image);
    list.appendChild(listItem);
    container.appendChild(list);
    container.classList.add('shopifyProduct');
    return container;
}
```

**Here is the HTML element when I inspect it with dev tools**

```
<li data-value="6736442654756" value="1933934628">Cactus Sneaker Women 6736442654756</li>
```

I am outputting the value in the `innerHTML` as well just to see if somehow where I output it changes its value.
As you can see in the above function the variable: `id` is being assigned to both attributes yet different values end up being assigned?

Has anyone encountered this strange behaviour before?

Thanks,
-Boogabooga

Comment: to demystify a little bit ... `1933934628 = 6736442654756 % 4294967296` and `typeof list.value === 'number'` ... why??? because `value` for `li` has an [actual meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attr-value), and it's obviously limited to 32bits

Comment: Note: according the HTML specs, the `value` is only relevant when `li` are children of `ol` ... when children of `ul` or `menu` (the only other valid parent of an `li`) then `value` is not "defined" ... also, there is no mention of the 32bit limit anywhere in the spec, just that `value` must be a **valid integer** - why would you want to use `.value` anyway

Comment: The reason I want to use `value` is so that when the list element is clicked on, its value will be put into an `input` in order to be sent with `$_POST[]` to the backend to be entered into the `database`. Sooo to understand this correctly, the number I am trying to put into the `value` is too long? Thanks for the reply btw :)

Comment: that makes no sense, `li` "value" would not be sent in a form submission anyway (would they?) - `when the list element is clicked on, its value will be put into an input` ... why not just use the `.dataset.value` in the click handler

Comment: no they wouldnt be. But the things in the `input` box would be, the `li` stuff is to provide for a user friendly interface, and yeah I'll use the `dataset.value` instead, was just confuzzled as to why they were returning different values. Is it because of the 32 bit integer limit?

Comment: sure, but you have to write code that "copies" the value from the clicked element to a (hidden?) input - that code is allowed to use `.dataset.value` just as it uses `.value` now

Comment: I don't get why you set both `value` and `dataset.value` in the first place. Why does the element (regardless of buginess you've uncovered) need the id twice?

Comment: Well I set `value` first, and got an unexpected result, and then I set `dataset.value` and got the expected result, and this confused me. So I will NOT be using both, I'll just use the one that gives me the correct value. I was more looking for answers (which you provided) as to why they had different results :)

Comment: ahh, all good then, that makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to demystify the result ... `1933934628 = 6736442654756 % 4294967296` and `typeof list.value === 'number'` ...

As to why???

The `value` attribute for `li` has an [actual meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attr-value), and it's obviously limited to 32bits

Note: according the [HTML specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), the `li` element has the following properties

> Content attributes:
> `Global attributes`
> If the element is not a child of an `ul` or `menu` element: `value` — Ordinal value of the list item

So, `value` is only relevant when `li` are children of `ol` ... when children of `ul` or `menu` (the only other valid parent of an `li`) then `value` is not "defined"

Seems some (most?) browsers aren't "up to spec" on this ...

Also, there is no mention of the 32bit limit anywhere in the spec, just that `value` must be a **valid integer**

In short, don't use `value` attributes on any elements that don't have that as a "native" attribute, like input for example

You're using `data-value` already, so stick with that